# Filter and count QuerySet items with a variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am new to Django and am working on a very basic social media site as a practice project.

Right now, I am trying to figure out how to filter a QuerySet based on a variable and counting how many items in the QuerySet match the filter.

To demonstrate what I am trying to do, let's say I am looping through all the visible posts (like a Facebook post or something similar), and I am wanting to display the number of comments each post has.

This is how I would go about that:

```
{% post in all_posts %}
    <h1> There are currently {{ HOW DO I FILTER AND COUNT? }} comments on this post</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

This is what the relevant section of my `views.py` file looks like:

```
def index(request):
    all_posts = Posts.objects.order_by('-date_published')
    all_comments = Comments.objects.order_by('-date_published')
    context = {'all_posts': all_posts,
               'all_comments': all_comments
              }
    return render(request, 'social/index.html', context)
```

The comments link to the posts through the postID variable. So, I know this doesn't work, but ideally I would like to replace my `HOW DO I FILTER AND COUNT?` part of the template with something like:

`{{ all_comments.filter(postID=post).count }}`

Is there an easy way to do this in my `views.py` or in the template itself? The main problem I have is that I do not know how I can pass the `post` variable in the template to some function that return the count I am looking for.

UPDATE:

Below are my Posts and Comments models:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     content = models.TextField()
     date_published = models.DateTimeField('date posted')

 class Comments(models.Model):
     postID = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     commenter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
     content = models.TextField()
     date_published = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
```

Comment: can you share the `Posts` and `Comments` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just updated the post with those models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `Posts` model objects with the number of `Comments` with:

```
def index(request):
    all_posts = Posts.objects.annotate(
        ncomments=Count('comments')
    ).order_by('-date_published')
    all_comments = Comments.objects.order_by('-date_published')
    context = {
        'all_posts': all_posts,
        'all_comments': all_comments
    }
    return render(request, 'social/index.html', context)
```

In the template you can then render this with:

```
{% post in all_posts %}
    <h1> There are currently {{ post.ncomments }} comments on this post</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Post` instead of <s>`Posts`</s>.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! Also thanks for the tip on naming conventions.